# Implementing login manually with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session

I am developing an application with Spring Boot. I now want to implement account control, and I'm introducing Spring Session and Spring Security. This is a back-end application based on REST services, the front-end will be a separate application consuming those services. I want to control that every user accessing the resources is logged in.

I don't want Spring Security to handle the login automatically, I want to implement my custom login service, in my already existing CustomerController, which is controlling other services.

My Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity loginSubmit(@RequestBody LoginForm form) {
        Errors errors = authenticationService.validateLoginForm(form);
        if (!errors.hasErrors()) {
            CustomerDTO result = authenticationService.findCustomerByEmailAndPassword(form);
            return new ResponseEntity(result, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity(errors.getAllErrors(), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity testBrowser() {
        return new ResponseEntity("Hello world", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    [ . . . Other services . . . ]
}
```

Spring Security configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/customer/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/h2-console/**");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

Effectively, this restricts all unlogged users from accessing any service, except login. In my controller, I've got two login methods implemented. One is a GET for testing purposes, the other one is a POST. When I access with the browser (GET) it works and I can hit the breakpoint. However when I try the POST (via Postman) it returns 401 Unauthorised, like the rest of the services that require login. The breakpoint never gets hit.

I believe I'm following the pattern. What am I missing please?

Comment: If you don't want to use Spring's login methodology why you call `.formLogin()`?

Comment: I do it in order to have a login handler, and exclude it from the restricted methods. If you think this is not how it's done please feel free to answer the question. I'm asking precisely how it should be done.

Comment: Simply don't as this gives you more issues than it solves, you loose a great part of the build in features which you would have to manually integrate into your controller. If you don't want to use the regular Spring Security login that is fine but then create another filter to use in the filter chain so that you integrate with all the Spring Security stuff instead of trying to cobble that together in a controller.

Comment: As stated create a filter and integratie it in the security chain. Also what is wrong with the normal Spring Security filter? Why not simply use that, apparently you still pass a username and password (in the body as JSON/XML or whatever) and validate that. Spring Security does exactly that. Looking at what you have the only difference is that you use JSON/XML for the transfer instead of a regular form.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you. I'm trying to figure out what's the best practice, and whether I should entrust Security to do everything, or customise it. Also, what do you mean by filter? Is that the same as a validator?

Comment: If you don't trust Spring Security then why use it? Next to that why wouldn't you trust a well tested and widely used security library to do all that stuff for you?

Comment: @M.Deinum I never said I didn't trust it, I was wondering whether to _entrust_ the use case to Spring, or overtake control over it. Nevertheless, your position on this matter is clear, thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Well authentication is part of the whole security thing. You can do it yourself however you would also need to manually integrate with Spring Security then to make the authorization part work with Spring Security. As Spring Security supports both and makes it fairly easy to integrate your own authentication filter in the chain I would suggest using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parameters mentioned in spring security docs:

1. login-page
2. login-processing-url

First one is where user will be redirected using GET in case if not logged, and the second one is where login page's form is submitted using POST.

You are receiving 401 Unauthorised because the default value for login-processing-url is /login and not /customer/login

docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/

Comment: This looks like the right answer but I still hit the same problem. I've tried .formLogin().loginPage("/customer/login").loginProcessingUrl("/customer/login").permitAll() and also tried giving them different endpoint names @MaximMarkov but still the same 401 result.

Comment: @bohemian Please post your complete class which extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in order for us to have a better picture.

Comment: @IanLim the whole class is stated above in the question, the only change is, where it said `.loginPage(` it now says `.loginProcessingUrl(`. Still same effect: 401, the method doesn't get hit. I get the same result when I include both `loginPage` and `loginProcessingUrl`.

Comment: As M. Denium already commented, you are doing something wrong in general. Spring security framework gives you a lot of ways to configure and extend it, but you decided to replace the core part of it's functionality. The standard way to authenticate user is to configure "login processing url" which is then handled by UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter, you can feed it with your custom source of users by implementing UserDeatailsService interface and registering it as bean.